# How do i present a navigation drawer over the center controller, with transparency?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, navigation-drawer

I am using the MMDrawerController library, but the default behaviour is that the center view is "pushed" to the right when the navigation drawer appears. I'd like the navigation drawer to appear on top of the current view, with a transparent background so that you can see the old view behind it. I can't find any examples of doing this online, is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

From the MMDrawerController docs:

> #### What this Library Doesn't Do
>
> In order to keep this library light-weight, we had to make some design trade off decisions. Specifically, we decided this library would NOT DO the following:
>
> […]
>
> - Support presenting the drawer above the center view controller (like the Google+ app).

This library doesn't support that. You can write a patch for it, or try out a different library.